# fullscreen textarea without scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea that I want to fill up the entire screen. Everyway I try it goes enough beyond the screen to need scrollbars.

I'm doing this to fill it up:

```
$('textarea').width($(window).width()).height($(window).height());
```

If you check out this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7BwaQ/)** you can see that it goes too far and that it then needs scrollbars. Is there a way to have it fill up the entire screen and not need scrollbars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing to do with javascript, you just did not noticed, pre-defined browser defaults for elements. Use this in your CSS stylesheet:

```
textarea { border: none; }
body { padding: 0; }
```

Comment: also `body{overflow: hidden;}` will remove the scrollbars none the less border and padding should be added too :)

Answer (score 4):

Use add some css.

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
textarea { border: 0; }
```